# Function is not calling in angular js when ng-change event occurs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the code below i have studied several blogs but note found any way to resolve this problem.

**HTML File:-**

```
<ion-content ng-controller="IpScanner">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Barcode"  ng-model="IpValue" ng-change="CartAction()" >
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

**JSFile**

```
.controller('IpScanner', ['$scope', 'socket', function($scope, socket, $window, $timeout, $ionicPopup, $q) {
  $scope.CartAction = function() {
    window.alert('Onchange');
  }
}])
```

Comment: I don't see a single `ng-change` anywhere in the markup you have provided.

Comment: i am sorry now i have done this you can check in my post

Comment: Create a demo that replicates problem. Not really clear what actual problem is

Comment: Thank you for your response i have resolved it was problem of cycles of angular i.e.$apply,$digest

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was just a matter of bad cut and paste or freehand typing in, but your controller is not well-formed. You have an extra closing bracket (`}`) in there. Try this:

```
.controller('IpScanner', ['$scope', 'socket', '$window', '$timeout', '$ionicPopup', '$q', function($scope, socket, $window, $timeout, $ionicPopup, $q) {
    $scope.CartAction = function()
    {
        window.alert('Onchange');
    }
}]);
```